# Create 2 dim List from 2 Dim list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2 dim List where I need to create a new 2 dim List but only using certain elements form the original one:

The original list looks like this:

`a = [['Volvo',100,200,300],['SAAB',10,20,30],['Ford',7,8,9]]`

and I need to create a new 2 dimensional list that picks element 1 and 4 from the original list:

`[['Volvo',300],['SAAB',30],['Ford',9]]`

This is how I started building the solution but I don't understand how to create the new List? I don't think I can use append?

```
num_cols = len(a[0])
num_rows = len(a)
for i in range(num_rows)
  elem_1 = a[i][0]
  elem_2 = a[i][num_cols-1]
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
arr_2d=[]
for x in range(num_rows):
   column_elements = []
   for y in range(num_cols):
       # Enter the all the values w.r.t to a particular column
       column_elements.append(a[x][0])
       column_elements.append(a[x][num_cols-1])
   #Append the column to the array.
   arr_2d.append(column_elements)
print(arr_2d)
```

Comment: Why don't you think you can use `append()`? Did you try to use it? What problem did you run into when you tried?

Comment: You can in fact append. new_list.append(elem_1,elem_2). This will results to new_list[0] = ['Volvo',300]. This is due to append's nature of only increasing the end of the list by 1 element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) and how to provide a [mre]. It is _your_ job to tell us what's wrong with your code. This usually involves including the actual output from your [mre] in the question, and describing why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: In this case, running the code shows that your desired elements appear in the new list multiple times. Can you think about why? Are you doing something that will append those elements multiple times? Do you _need_ to do that? Now is a good time to learn [how to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Step through your code in a
[debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) and observe the values of your variables as you do this, and your mistake quickly becomes pretty evident. Debugging is a crucial skill for a programmer to have.

Comment: @March_G new_list.append(elem_1, elem_2) gives me the following error: TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: new_list.append([elem_1, elem_2]) it just needed a bracket. Now it is appending a list and should work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a new list. In which case a trivial list comprehension will help you - i.e., no explicit loop constructs required:

```
a = [['Volvo',100,200,300],['SAAB',10,20,30],['Ford',7,8,9]]

b = [[e[0], e[-1]] for e in a]

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Volvo', 300], ['SAAB', 30], ['Ford', 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem. many thanks for the help!

```
num_cols = len(a[0])
arr_2d=[]
for x in range(number_of_rows):
   
    column_elements = []
    column_elements.append(a[x][0])
    column_elements.append(int(a[x][num_cols - 1]))

    arr_2d.append(column_elements)

print(arr_2d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer:

```
a = [['Volvo', 100, 200, 300], ['SAAB', 10, 20, 30], ['Ford', 7, 8, 9]]
final_list = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    b = [a[i][0], a[i][-1]]
    final_list.append(b)

print(final_list)
```

and it will print this:

```
[['Volvo', 300], ['SAAB', 30], ['Ford', 9]]
```

note:

- There is no `:` at the end of `for` loop
- Didn't add new variable to the list

Comment: OP wants a new list

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right.